# How can I complete a data.table column with values from this column?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table()` with the columns : **city**,**month**, **year** and **gdp_per_capta** - by year, its value repeat all months. (actually I have 30 more columns)

My base is full fill from 2005 to 2018.
But, to the year 2019, the gdp_per_capta has **NA**.

I would like to put a value on it, this way: *2019 = (2018/2017) * 2018*

How can I do it?

*PS: How can I improve the title of this question?*

Example of my data:

```
structure(list(city = c(110001L, 110001L, 110001L, 110001L, 
                                      110001L, 110001L, 110001L, 110001L, 110001L, 110001L, 110001L, 
                                      110001L, 110037L, 110037L, 110037L, 110037L, 110037L, 110037L, 
                                      110037L, 110037L, 110037L, 110037L, 110037L, 110037L, 110040L, 
                                      110040L, 110040L, 110040L, 110040L, 110040L, 110040L, 110040L, 
                                      110040L, 110040L, 110040L, 110040L), month = c("01", "04", "07", 
                                                                                   "10", "02", "05", "08", "11", "03", "06", "09", "12", "01", "04", 
                                                                                   "07", "10", "02", "05", "08", "11", "03", "06", "09", "12", "01", 
                                                                                   "04", "07", "10", "02", "05", "08", "11", "03", "06", "09", "12"
                                      ), year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
                                                 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 
                                                 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2017L, 2017L, 
                                                 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
                                                 2019L), gdp_per_capta = c(19081.43, 19081.43, 19081.43, 
                                                                                  19081.43, 21552.47, 21552.47, 21552.47, 21552.47, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                  NA, 23353.6, 23353.6, 23353.6, 23353.6, 21053.93, 21053.93, 21053.93, 
                                                                                  21053.93, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14699.7, 14699.7, 14699.7, 14699.7, 
                                                                                  15655.57, 15655.57, 15655.57, 15655.57, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                          -36L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

My expected result is in red:
[image]

Comment: Error in `[.data.table`(dt, is.na(pib_per_capta),  : 
  Supplied 64956 items to be assigned to 65496 items of column 'gdp_per_capta'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Comment: I also have the column `month`, but the `gdp_per_capta` repeat the value per year.

Comment: That probably tells you that not all values for 2019 are NA. Just a guess. You might want to check that and update your example data.

Comment: I just updated. All gdp_per_capta values are NA for 2019 year. It will be only one value per city in all months

Comment: Works here still: `dt[is.na(gdp_per_capta), gdp_per_capta := dt[, gdp_per_capta[year == 2018]^2 / gdp_per_capta[year == 2017], by=city]$V1]
`

Comment: Same error here :( And I don't get the `$V1` at the end

Comment: How does `month` apply here? In 2017, there's `01`,`04`,`07`,`10`, and each year later the months are incremented (2,5,8,11; 3,6,9,12). Do you not strictly care about the month value so much as its ordinal position within the year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question is tagged with `data.table`, Here are two `data.table` approaches:

### 1. `fifelse()`

```
DT[, gdp_per_capta := fifelse(is.na(gdp_per_capta) & year == 2019L, 
                              last(gdp_per_capta[year == 2018L])^2 / last(gdp_per_capta[year == 2017L]),
                              gdp_per_capta), by = city][]
```

### 2. join & `fcoalesce()`

Here, a table containing the replacement values is being joined:

```
rDT <- DT[, .(year = 2019L, last(gdp_per_capta[year == 2018L])^2 / last(gdp_per_capta[year == 2017L])), 
          by = city]
DT[rDT, on = .(city, year), gdp_per_capta := fcoalesce(x.gdp_per_capta, i.V2)][]
```

The replacement table `rDT` is

```
rDT
```

> ```
>      city year       V2
> 1: 110001 2019 24343.51
> 2: 110037 2019 18980.71
> 3: 110040 2019 16673.60
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that `month` is ordinal and not numeric. Because my solution pivots, I'll temporarily move `month` out of the way in lieu of integers.

```r
# store the real month/month_i translation, per-city/year
DT0 <- DT[, .(city, month, year, month_i)]

# pivot wide, calculate, then melt-long
DTnew <- DT[, month := NULL] %>%
  dcast(., city + month_i ~ year, value.var = "gdp_per_capta") %>%
  .[, `2019` := (`2018`/`2017`)*`2018`] %>%
  melt(id.vars = c("city", "month_i"), variable.name = "year", value.name = "gdp_per_capta",
       variable.factor = FALSE) %>%
  .[, year := as.integer(year) ]
DTnew
#       city month_i  year gdp_per_capta
#      <int>   <int> <int>         <num>
#  1: 110001       1  2017      19081.43
#  2: 110001       2  2017      19081.43
#  3: 110001       3  2017      19081.43
#  4: 110001       4  2017      19081.43
#  5: 110037       1  2017      23353.60
# ---                                   
# 32: 110037       4  2019      18980.71
# 33: 110040       1  2019      16673.60
# 34: 110040       2  2019      16673.60
# 35: 110040       3  2019      16673.60
# 36: 110040       4  2019      16673.60

# rejoin to bring back the original months
DTnew <- DT0[DTnew, on = .(city, month_i, year)][, month_i := NULL]
DTnew
#       city  month  year gdp_per_capta
#      <int> <char> <int>         <num>
#  1: 110001     01  2017      19081.43
#  2: 110001     04  2017      19081.43
#  3: 110001     07  2017      19081.43
#  4: 110001     10  2017      19081.43
#  5: 110037     01  2017      23353.60
# ---                                  
# 32: 110037     12  2019      18980.71
# 33: 110040     03  2019      16673.60
# 34: 110040     06  2019      16673.60
# 35: 110040     09  2019      16673.60
# 36: 110040     12  2019      16673.60
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice way to solve this! Brings me a new perspective

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution! For data that `is.na` and `year == 2019` take the first value of 2018 & first value of 2017 to calculate as your formula.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(gdp_per_capta_revised = if_else(is.na(gdp_per_capta) & year == 2019,
                                 (first(gdp_per_capta[year == 2018]) / 
                                    first(gdp_per_capta[year == 2017])) *
                                   first(gdp_per_capta[year == 2018]),
                                  gdp_per_capta))
```

Here is the brief look at the result for those `NA` in 2019 - The other year will have same value as original `gdp_per_capta`.

```
     city month  year gdp_per_capta gdp_per_capta_revised
    <int> <chr> <int>         <dbl>                 <dbl>
 1 110001 03     2019            NA                24344.
 2 110001 06     2019            NA                24344.
 3 110001 09     2019            NA                24344.
 4 110001 12     2019            NA                24344.
 5 110037 03     2019            NA                18981.
 6 110037 06     2019            NA                18981.
 7 110037 09     2019            NA                18981.
 8 110037 12     2019            NA                18981.
 9 110040 03     2019            NA                16674.
10 110040 06     2019            NA                16674.
11 110040 09     2019            NA                16674.
12 110040 12     2019            NA                16674.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I needed  a `data.table` solution, but this sure helped a lot! I didn't know we could filter  the year in this way.